# Mootools: get text from clicked link's sibling table node

Tags: select, mootools, siblings

here's the situation:

```
| ID | Name   | ...
+----+--------+---
| 12 | Henry  | ...     a whole list of names, ids,&c ...you get the idea
+----+--------+---
| 13 | Julia  | ...
+-------------+---
...
```

all the names are links.  when selected, they load the rest of the table for editing by passing the name into a quick mysql query.  but since i'm getting dupes, i need to grab the id as well to pass along.  i also need it for updating the corrected (and correct!) record.

so, using MooTools, how do i grab the text from the neighbouring sibling when i click the link?  hell, even just plain ol' JS will do.

here's the existing function:

```
function loadRecord(aName) {
  console.log("loadRecord called with: "+aName);
  user = $('submitterName').value;
  id = $('table-id').text; //  THIS IS THE PROBLEM RIGHT HERE.  >_<
  console.log('with user: '+user);
  $('recordName').value = aName;
  $('addRecordButton').value = 'Update Record';
  $('addRecordData').action='_php/updateRecord.php';  // this isn't working either...
  var action=$('addRecordData').action;
  console.log(action);
  checkUserDB(aName,user,id);
}
```

since there are multiple rows to the table, i can't assign a unique identifier to each ID  to any benefit.  i'm still stuck trying to pull the table-id's text that relates to the clicked link.

i hope i am clear.  any help or illumination would be much appreciated.

TIA crew!

WR!

Comment: Can you paste a example of your HTML? and explain what you think `$('table-id').text` does? Is that string always the same? why are you not using MooTools's `get('text')`, why not add the ID you want in the link clicked like a `data-` field?

Comment: $('table-id).text returns the text in the element.  don't know how to implement the moo-data plugin, or i would use a data- field.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution**

> **`HTML`**

```
<!--Change your HTML-->
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td><a>Henry</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><a>Julia</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> **`MooTools`**

```
window.addEvent('load', function(){
  window.addEvent('click:relay(a)', function(event){//Add your selector inside relay
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).getParent('td').getPrevious().get('html'));
    //Add Your AJAX code here
  });
});
```

> Here you are attaching a **`click event`** to anchor then **`selecting`**
>   **`parent`**(http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.2/Element/Element#Element:getParent)
>   then as you have ID in **`previous`**
>   **`element`**(http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.2/Element/Element#Element:getPrevious)
>   you can **`grab the previous element and get it's HTML`**

You can check the pen here http://codepen.io/arifmahmudrana/pen/yYQeJX

Comment: excellent!  i had the structure, thanks for the code.  you explained it very clearly and i really appreciate that, because i understand the solution.

Comment: @WhiteRau thanks then please upvote & select it as right answer.